# Является ли предложение, в котором повторены подлежащее и сказуемое, сложным?

Tags: синтаксис

И там на подушке из ярких песков,
Под тенью густых тростников,
Спит витязь, добыча ревнивой волны,
Спит витязь чужой стороны. (М. Ю. Лермонтов)

Предложение из учебника русского языка для 7 класса (автор Г. Граник). Думаю, не только мне интересно: если в предложении две одинаковые грамматические основы, является ли оно сложным? Заранее благодарна.

Comment: Катя, в учебнике такой вопрос задается или просто у Вас возник вопрос по поводу напечатанного?

Comment: Лара, здравствуйте! Нужно было сделать синтаксический разбор этого предложения. Поэтому оказалось важным, простое предложение или сложное. Я сказала, что простое, но пообещала задать вопрос на форуме. На следующий день дети спросили, задала ли я вопрос, а я забыла... Пришлось срочно исправляться).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Думаю, что предложение все-таки простое, повтор играет стилистическую роль. Правда, не могу, к сожалению, сослаться на конкретный источник с похожими предложениями и точным ответом. Но подобное явление часто описывается в учебниках. Я имею в виду характеристику сказуемого в предложениях типа *он шел, шел и пришел*. В предложении два простых глагольных сказуемых: шел, шел и пришел. Повтор слова не осложняет структуру предложения, не делает сказуемое  составным. В предложении из вопроса такой же пример, только другого структурного уровня. Вопрос только, нужно ли это семиклассникам? Не запутает ли их?

Comment: Спасибо, Лара.

Comment: Вот нашла характеристику этого приёма:  Эпанафора (анадиплосис), или стык – прием, при котором конец предложения повторяется в начале следующегоhttp://www.listos.biz/%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8/

Comment: Здесь ясно сказано, что это разные предложения. Есть пример:Я на башню всходил, и дрожали ступени,
И дрожали ступени под ногой у меня.Точь-в-точь наш пример. Согласна, что есть разные точки зрения на это, но чтобы разбирали как простое - не видела. Есть и с точкой-как парцелляция:«Все мы ожидаем друг от друга понимания наших сокровенных желаний. Наших сокровенных желаний, исполнения которых мы все втайне ждем».Второе - неполное, парцеллированное.

Comment: Простите, но там сказано следующее: "Эпанафора (анадиплосис), или стык – прием, при котором конец предложения повторяется в начале следующего. «Все мы ожидаем друг от друга понимания наших сокровенных желаний. Наших сокровенных желаний, исполнения которых мы все втайне ждем»".  
У нас никак не анадиплосис... Посмотрите внимательно)).

Answer (score 10):

Повтор как фигура речи может представлять из себя повтор слов, повтор словосочетаний и повтор предложений. В русском языке грамматическая основа всё-таки является предложением, значит, это повтор предложения. Для 7 класса не дали бы конструкции с таким сложным и спорным анализом, думаю, автор имел в виду, что это два предложения с повторяющейся основой (как худ. приём). Он шел, шел и пришел - совсем другая конструкция, здесь повтор слова(сказуемого). Насчёт одной ситуации и количества витязей:
В примере: Во поле березонька стояла, во поле кудрявая стояла - ситуация одна, и берёза одна, а предложений два, это симплока - сочетание анафоры и эпифоры, в смежных стихах.

Это отдельные предложения, каждое имеет своё значение, поэтому предложение сложное бессоюзное. Одинаковых основ может быть много.
Если бы повторялись только сказуемые: спит, спит витязь - учитывалось бы только одно повторяющееся сказуемое (не однородные члены, а одно) Или вот:

Клянусь я первым днем творенья,
Клянусь его последним днем,
Клянусь позором преступленья
И вечной правды торжеством.

Клянусь паденья горькой мукой,
Победы краткою мечтой;
Клянусь свиданием с тобой
И вновь грозящею разлукой. 
(М. Лермонтов)

Это отдельные предложения. Первое двусоставное, дальше - односоставные.
Представьте себе, что Вы указываете в анализе: простое, осложнённое... чем? повтором? - нет такого осложнения в русском языке.

Comment: Да с детьми-то я разберу это предложение как сложное. А вот что это в грамматике... Поэтический синтаксис особый, как и синтаксис разговорной речи. Хорошо бы где-нибудь почитать. Я не нашла. Про сказуемые: я понимаю, что это другое. И в ответе об этом упоминаю. Но никто же не говорит, что в предложении "он шел, шел..." - два сказуемых, а говорят об одном, простом глагольном. Почему ту же логику нельзя применить к повтору грамматической основы?

Comment: Людмила,благодарю Вас, но я не повтор имела в виду, конечно, когда говорила "осложнённое"). Я имела в виду обособленные члены предложения).

Comment: И всё-таки детей Вы запутаете, предложение сложное, потому что здесь две основы, хотя они и повторяющиеся. Фигура речи здесь имеет не только стилистическую функцию, но и синтаксическую,лексический повтор выражается конструкцией, занимающей 2 позиции, это сложное предложение.

Comment: А как с "Клянусь"? Это простое с однородными членами или бессоюзное сложное с односоставными?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, это сложносочиненное предложение. *Спит витязь* - основы.

Answer (score 2):

Сложное, но не сложносочиненное, а бессоюзное сложное

Comment: Я думаю, поэтический размер заставил повторить ГО, но этот повтор не может увеличить кол-во витязей на берегу))) Простое распространенное?

Comment: )))Спасибо!Я тоже думаю, что предложение всё-таки простое. "Сложное предложение - это целостная синтаксическая единица, представляющая собой грамматически оформленное сочетание предложений и функционирующая в качестве сообщения о двух или более ситуациях и об отношениях между ними". (http://rusgram.narod.ru/2753-2764.html)  
А у нас "ситуация" одна, повтор используется как средство выразительности. Простое осложнённое?

Comment: Простое, осложненное повтором грамматической основы) Тема повторов в русской грамматике явно не разработана. 
"*Я мечтал об этом всегда, я мечтал об этом всю жизнь.*"

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, предложение всё-таки простое, осложнённое уточняющим оборотом. Уберите второе "спит",  - изменится ритмика, смысл не пострадает.

Answer (score 2):

Интересный вопрос. Я бы все-таки сказал, что это сложное предложение.

Рассуждаю я просто. Ничто, никакое правило грамматики не запрещает использовать две одинаковые основы, ничему это не противоречит.

Но стоит счесть предложение простым, сразу возникают вопросы. Даже вот такая вещь, те, кто говорит о простом, расходятся в определении грамматики, начинаются споры о допустимости такого рефрена, приходится ссылаться на какие-то второстепенные моменты, ссылки на требования стихотворного размера (это у Лермонтова-то! Который ни одной буквы не написал просто для того, чтобы строчку заполнить!). И самое главное, как мешает рефрен (факт его наличия) трактовке предложения как сложного? Рефрен - стилистический прием, он здесь имеет место, не спорю. Но грамматика все равно сложного предложения. Две основы, пусть и одинаковые.

И еще. Детям, конечно, нельзя такие вопросы задавать. А между нами, взрослыми, вопрос представляется несколько схоластическим. На правописание не влияет, на понимание смысла - тем более. Так почему не пойти по самому простому пути? Бритва Оккама - она, родная.

Answer (score 2):

Может уже поздно, но все же опубликую ответ Граммы.ру. Задавал этот вопрос им давно, однако потом забыл их ответ здесь опубликовать.

Постановка вопроса о том, является ли это повтором или сложным предложением, не вполне корректна: "повтор" - понятие из стилистики, "сложное предложение" - грамматический термин.

К предложению можно подойти подойти с двух точек зрения - содержательной и формальной.
**С формальной точки зрения предложение** 
И там на подушке из ярких песков,
Под тенью густых тростников,
Спит витязь, добыча ревнивой волны,
Спит витязь чужой стороны.
должно быть квалифицировано **как сложное,** **так как здесь две грамматические основы**. **Их полное совпадение не является основанием для признания предложения простым: грамматическая основа является выразителем грамматических категорий предложения (лицо, модальность, время) и делает предложение коммуникативной единицей. Таким образом, с формальной точки зрения (школьной) это сложное бессоюзное предложения.**
**С содержательной точки зрения** предложение является выразителем ситуации во **внеязыковой действительности (пропозиции**). Приведенный пример показывает, что эта сложная **структура, которая состоит из двух предикативных частей и должна выражать две ситуации,** в действительности является **монопропозитивной, т**о есть функционально с**овпадающей с простым предложением.** 
Явление повтора состоит именно в том, чтобы была нарушена симметрия между планом выражения и планом содержания в пользу плана выражения с целью воздействия на адресата текста.

С уважением

GRAMMA.RU

Answer (score 0):

Это простое предложение, осложненное однородными членами и обособленным приложением.

Answer (score 0):

Я не рискую навязывать свое представление, когда речь идет о детях, педагогика - это отдельная поле, но безотносительно к ним, попробую бросить свои пять копеек.

Мнения - это конечно хорошо, но даваqте объективно взвесим все pro et contra.

Довод за простое предложение: вставка союза "и", которая возможна почти всегда в бессоюзных предложения приводит к некоторой неразберихе со смыслом: один ли это витязь спит, разные ли это сны и проч.

Довод против: я как-то не могу вспомнить в грамматике что-то подобное рефрену из *полной грамматической основы*.

Второй довод против: когда грамматика позволяет применить две трактовки, руководствоваться надо более глобальной, базовой. Естественно, грамматическая основа  предложения - вещь куда более мощная в сравнении с риторическими фигурами.

Третий довод против: А какой смысл тут в рефрене? Я понимаю, было бы "Витязь спит и спит".

Пожалуй, "против" перевешивает. Я за сложносочиненное.

ЗЫ Перед написанием я очень мельком просмотрел ответы, только чтобы не повторяться. Удивлен, что мы с Людмилой пришли к одному выводу разными путями. Обычно бывает наоборот, рассуждаем в общем-то одинаково (если не придираться к манере изложения), приходим к противоположным выводам.

Comment: Вы правы: в сложном предложении между частями устанавливается или сочинительная, или подчинительная связь. Здесь, по мнению многих, бессоюзие. Попробуем вставить сочинительный союз  между частями. Ничего не получится. С подчинительным союзом тоже.  "Отношения, складывающиеся между предложениями при бессоюзии, могут получать неграмматическое выражение с помощью определенных, в разной степени специализированных элементов лексики: местоименных слов, частиц, вводных слов и наречий". У нас ничего такого нет. Предложение простое. Повтор помогает красиво применить два разных определения к "витязю".