# Как решать нестандартные лингвистические задачи

Tags: методика

Нестандартные задачи – не редкость в нашей практике. Какова же методика их решения? Эта тема связана напрямую с одним из заданных вопросов [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464188/Предложение-сложное-или-с-однородными-членами](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464188/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Меня там заинтересовал как первый ответ, так и комментарии автора ответа к нему, где он дает некоторые пояснения.

Сначала, как я думаю, надо определить характер задачи – стандартная она или нестандартная.

**Стандартные** задачи решаются по правилам, причем на правило в общем случае нужно давать ссылку. Иногда требуется знание грамматики, тогда тоже желательно указывать авторитетный источник.

Некоторые задачи, решаемые по правилам, имеют **варианты** – в этом случае для их различения можно использовать интонационный и семантический анализ. Это более сложный уровень задач.

Но есть задачи, которые требуют **особого подхода**.

Как вы решаете такие задачи, есть ли у  вас какие-то «секреты»?

Я же в своем ответе попробую рассказать о своей «методике».

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Комментарий, который я собиралась дать к первому ответу**

Интересный у вас подход – детальная формализация, и всё такое. А давайте рассуждать так. Все мы в школе изучали **математику**. Нам объясняли какую-то тему, давали решения типовых задач.  Потом мы решали их сами, закрепляли материал и переходили к следующей теме. Но вот курс закончен, мы получили какой-то **багаж знаний и умений**, который можем применять на практике.

***И вот перед нами задача, только мы и она***. И это итоговая проверка всех знаний. Нет рядом учителя, нет тетради с готовыми решениями, всё зависит от нас – какую методику выберем, с чего начнем, что посчитаем важным, а что нет.

И если решить не получается, то надо определить, что знаем недостаточно, еще раз проработать эту тему. Вот только **формализаций  и готовых решений**  брать с собой нежелательно. Просто вернуться к исходной ситуации: ***вот перед нами задача, только мы и она.*** Такой подход, как мне кажется, нужен в любой области знаний.

**В языке то же самое,**  никаких отличий. Но это мой способ получения и применения знаний. Насколько он успешен, проверяется практикой. Если вам ближе другой вариант, это ваш выбор, но **скидок** нам никто не сделает и **времени** на подготовку не даст. В конкурентной среде ценится только **результат.**

**2. Рассмотрим в качестве примера эту тему.**

***Не было ни жилья, ни людей, не было ни рыбаков, ни сплавщиков, ни косарей, ни охотников.*** Это сложное предложение или "не было" – однородные сказуемые?

Ответ первый

Договоренность, условность – звучит красиво, но  в чем она заключается  и чего касается? Это тема **безличных** предложений? Но безличность связана с отрицательной формой глагола *не было*, такие предложения возможны и при утверждении: *Было жилье, люди,  были рыбаки, сплавщики, косари, охотники.*  Вопрос сохраняется, значит, не в безличности дело.

**Путь оказался неверным**, но автор ответа этого не замечает, в комментарии он по-прежнему говорит о безличных предложениях.

Ответ второй

Я сразу обратила внимание на этот вопрос, но отвечать не стала. Надо было подумать, послушать другие ответы.  Тогда только обсуждался похожий вопрос с **повтором** глагола «вижу», но у меня еще не было мнения, что повтор может задавать **однозначность** выбора в пользу сложного предложения.

**Примечание.** Впрочем, никто так и не согласился с таким критерием, но тогда у меня такой ответ: проверьте в художественных текстах  наличие запятых в ССП перед союзом И при наличии повтора глагола.

Итак, повтор еще не критерий, а что тогда? Мне же нужна **однозначность,** иначе никого не убедишь. **Интонация?**  Да, пожалуй.  Однородный ряд – это перечислительная интонация, а здесь она явно прерывается. Да, это решение, остается только оформить.

Не было у меня особого опыта в решении таких задач, и никакой детальной формализации тоже не было.  Такая **формализация**  только помешает в начале решения и направит по ложному пути. **Начало рассуждения** – это тот момент, который особенно важен.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (примеры классификации задач)

От 25.04.2021 [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464239/Ставится-ли-запятая-перед-либо](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464239/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE)

Эта задача вызвала определенные трудности при решении. У Розенталя есть тема СПП с несколькими однородными придаточными, но он не рассматривает ее подробно для варианта с **разными сочинительными** союзами. Из отдельных тем  (§ 33, 35) можно понять **принцип** решения подобных задач. Он заключается в том, что **группировка** однородных придаточных может быть различной, но она сходна с однородными членами.

Поэтому эта  задача повышенной трудности из-за необходимости грамматического анализа, но она тоже **стандартная.** Это значит, что  решение уже существует, но его надо  определить **по грамматическим показателям**. Никакой собственной методики там не нужно.

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464251/А-я-бы-сказал-это-уточняющая-к](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/464251/%D0%90-%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA)

Задача  **однозначно стандартная**, решение нужно искать у Розенталя. Непонятно, с чем связана неопределенность в формулировках и отсутствие ссылок на правило.  Соответственно, автор вопроса затрудняется в выборе знака, а также в  обосновании этого выбора.

**ВЫВОД**

Классификация задач, как мне кажется, очень важна, так как определяет **направление поиска** с самого  начала – мы или работаем по известному  правилу, или понимаем, что нужен собственный подход. В случае **стандартных** задач это избавляет нас самих от расплывчатых мнений и неясных действий, а также позволяет проконтролировать другие ответы.

Comment: Sharon, схожий вопрос задавался на нашем сайте. Прочитайте мой ответ. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19166/%d0%af%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc

Comment: Да, Серж, спасибо за очень интересный материал, я всё прочитала (обошли его, однако, вниманием наши участники). Точка зрения Грамоты.ру кажется мне близкой для моего собственного понимания. Но повтор – он многоликий. Там повтор всей основы в художественных целях, верным представляется  только один вариант – две основы. У нас в одном случае повтор двух одинаковых глаголов и подстановка личного местоимения в качестве подлежащего (я вижу, и (я) вижу). Связь союзная, пунктуация меняется, но задача тоже художественная.

Comment: Во втором случае (не было, не было) связь бессоюзная, а разделение основ функциональное (обозначение границы между  обобщающим словом и однородным рядом), хотя пунктуация при этом не меняется. Но всё-таки  общая идея просматривается – везде ПОВТОР обозначает ДВЕ СИТУАЦИИ, две предикативные основы.

Comment: В том-то и дело, в обоих случаях две основы. Только не Грамота.ру, а Грамма.ру.