# Ставится ли запятая перед «либо»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

**Когда чёрный цвет надоел, а яркую обувь вы не рискуете надеть(,) либо она не подходит к случаю, советуем обратить внимание на благородный оттенок – бордо.**

Comment: Алина, еще совет. Не торопитесь принимать первый ответ, подождите хотя бы день-два. Вдруг будут другие мнения или более обстоятельные объяснения, которые понравятся больше, и тогда Вам захочется переставить галочку. Но в любом случае две галочки поставить нельзя, а вот стрелочки можно.

Comment: Очень жаль, что нельзя поставить две галочки, так как очень часто бывают возможны варианты)

Comment: Если переделать предложение вот так: «Когда чёрный цвет надоел, а яркую обувь вы не рискуете надеть либо яркая обувь не подходит к случаю, советуем обратить внимание на благородный оттенок – бордо» — то все станет очевидно.

Comment: Да, согласна. Так более понятно стало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая в приведенном предложении однозначно **не ставится**.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Все придаточные здесь однородные со значением времени,  к ним относится общий союз КОГДА.

Но между придаточными **особенная** связь. Союз ЛИБО (=ИЛИ) одиночный, он связывает предложения (2) и  (3) в единое целое – поэтому запятая не ставится, паузы там нет, иначе связь **не будет обозначена.**

К ним обоим относится союз А, выражающий значение **сопоставления** между предложением (1) и предложениями(2)и (3). Его можно считать общим элементом для (2) и (3).

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответы. 

Answer (score 2):

Перед разделительным союзом "либо" в данном случае **запятая не ставится**, так как все придаточные предложения являются однородными и относятся к одному главному.

[**Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139) (справочник Розенталя):

> 3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными) запятая не ставится: *Отец мой говорил, **что он не видывал таких хлебов и что нынешний год урожай отличный*** (Акс.); *Чудилось, **будто корчуют сразу весь лес и выдираемые из земли корни и сама земля стонут и вопят от боли*** (Фед.) — повторяющихся союзов здесь нет (первый союз *и* соединяет две придаточные части, второй — однородные подлежащие *корни* и *земля*, третий — однородные сказуемые *стонут* и *вопят*); ***Что это за соединение и кто такой Ковпак,*** мы тогда ещё не знали (Медв.).

**Дополнение**

Возможность поставить запятую, однако, существует, если мы применим интонационный анализ всего предложения, которое трудно прочитать без паузы перед "либо". Тогда этот союз приобретет и присоединительный характер, обязывающий каким-либо образом обозначить это на письме. В таком случае я бы вообще заключил в скобки третье предложение как альтернативу-добавку, попутное замечание:

*Когда чёрный цвет надоел, а яркую обувь вы не рискуете надеть (либо она не подходит к случаю), советуем обратить внимание на благородный оттенок – бордо.*

Да, всё предложение можно прочитать по-разному. Но если мы хотим, чтобы второе и третье предложения имели "одинаковый вес", стоит и можно прочитать их слитно, в одну фразу, – соответственно, обойтись без запятой.

Comment: Я тоже так рассуждала, потом запуталась.

Comment: Распутывайтесь!   Посмотрим на реакцию других участников. А пока я ухожу.

Comment: Александр, дополнение не кажется мне справедливым. Здесь интонация уже на втором плане, а на первом - грамматика, союз А связывает эти предложения. Мой ответ однозначный - запятая не ставится.

Comment: Да я же стал сомневаться,  начал крутить варианты. В итоге вариант с обособлением не соответствует не только грамматике, но и семантике. Поэтому в конце своего дополнения я делаю вывод о равноправности этих придаточных и ненужности запятой.

Comment: Сомневаться? Здесь лучше быть уверенным, это морально поддерживает. :)

Comment: Я почему-то (понятно почему) подумал, что вы сейчас напишете про возможные варианты. Пишу дополнение, отправляю, и тут же получаю ваш ответ, кучу комментариев, правок. Блеск! Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо всем за разъяснения)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, не к месту, но я все-таки выражу свое мнение по этому вопросу.
Не успела дать ответ по поводу запятой (она, конечно же, **не нужна** — правильные объяснения даны), но есть другой момент: *благородный оттенок — бордо.*
Бордо (бордовый) — это **цвет**, никак не оттенок.

Во избежание повтора слова "цвет" я вижу это предложение таким:
*Когда чёрный* [цвет] *надоел, а яркую обувь вы не рискуете надеть либо она не подходит к случаю, советуем обратить внимание на благородный цвет – бордо.*

Или таким (если вдруг хочется указать конкретно *оттенок* бордового):
*Когда чёрный цвет надоел, а яркую обувь вы не рискуете надеть либо она не подходит к случаю, советуем обратить внимание на благородный оттенок бордового* [цвета] *– бургунди.*

Белые гардины с гипюровыми прошивками, плюшевые портьеры и ламбрекены ― **цвета бордо**; портьеры подтянуты и взбиты, подобно рукавам на платье хозяйки дома... [Ю. П. Анненков (Б. Темирязев). Повесть о пустяках (1934)]

[Оттенки бордового цвета](https://malva-shop.com.ua/a310151-bordovyj-tsvet-ego.html)

Comment: Уточнение уместно)

Comment: И Вам, Алана, спасибо — Ваш вопрос интересен.