# "А я бы сказал" — это уточняющая конструкция?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

**Зелёные, а я бы сказал изумрудные, озера.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы расставила знаки так:
**Зелёные, а я бы сказал, изумрудные озера.**

Здесь, думаю, ***а я бы сказал*** является вводным предложением и выделяется с двух сторон запятыми (его без потери смысла можно изъять из предложения).
Нет контекста, поэтому сложно понять: есть уточнение или нет? Но запятая после "изумрудные", я считаю, в любом случае не нужна.

― Воровство, или, по мысли Фридриха Энгельса, наиболее примитивная стихийная форма протеста против частной собственности, **а я бы сказал,** против собственности вообще, ― это норма для большинства стран мира. [Юрий Азаров. Подозреваемый (2002)]

Сравните (*я бы сказал* — вводное):
Как это часто бывает в Токио, наш «джип» неожиданно свернул с большой улицы в какой-то даже не переулок, а, **я бы сказал,** щель, поднялся под углом чуть ли не в тридцать градусов на несколько десятков метров в гору, и мы вылезли у небольшого серо-черного, обычного для Японии цвета, дома. [Константин Симонов. Япония. 46 (1946-1976)]

**Дополнение** (после комментария)

Можно написать так:
— Зелёные? А я бы сказал, что изумрудные озёра.

Или так:
— Зелёные озёра? А я бы сказал — изумрудные.

Comment: Гид рассказывает о зелёных озёрах. Но туристу они кажутся изумрудного цвета. Поэтому я решила, что это относится к случаю, когда вводное слово или сочетание стоит в начале обособленного оборота.

Comment: Может, здесь можно и так и так оформить?

Comment: Зеленые (а я бы сказал изумрудные) озера. Зеленые, точнее, изумрудные озера.

Answer (score 1):

***Зелёные, а я бы сказал, изумрудные озера.***

Решение, безусловно, **одно,** да только его надо правильно **обосновать.**

Для начала классифицируем задачу.  Оборот по своему значению равен вводному слову «точнее».  Я считаю, что задача **стандартная, так как  есть готовое решение у Розенталя,** поэтому здесь нет необходимости сомневаться и предполагать.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118 (примечание 2 к п.4)

2. Уточняющий характер придают высказыванию слова ***вернее, точнее, иначе, скорее*** и т. п. Однако следующие за ними члены предложения **НЕ ОБОСОБЛЯЮТСЯ,** так как указанные слова, имеющие значение вводных (*точнее, вернее, иначе* по смыслу равнозначны словосочетаниям точнее говоря, вернее говоря, иначе говоря), **сами выделяются запятыми**:  *Совсем недавно, точнее, в последнем номере журнала была опубликована статья аналогичного содержания.*

**Примечание** (когда вводное слово относится к обороту и не обособляется)

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122 п.4

4. Если вводное слово (сочетание) **стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота** (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется:  Он вспоминал эти слова, возможно слышанные в детстве;  Мимо пробежал кто-то, по счастью нас не заметивший;  Девочка, по-видимому успокоенная, замолчала;

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Некоторую сложность можно усмотреть в определении отношений между определениями *зеленый* и *изумрудный*, однако в данном случае это не является принципиальным – оформление одно и то же, мы уточняем оттенок цвета.

Но если убрать вводное сочетание, то определения  следует оформить как **однородные** (они раскрывают одну тему, мы как бы подбираем более подходящий вариант): ***зеленые, изумрудные озера.***

Comment: _Sharon_, чем же Вам не по нраву мой ответ? Знаки я поставила правильно. Ответила, что это не уточняющая конструкция, а вводное предложение. Привела  примеры. Показала, как можно перестроить предложение. Извините, наверно, и вправду виновата: позволила себе сомневаться и предполагать.

Comment: Знаете, Sharon, я думала, что мы тут с упоением занимаемся русским языком, а оказывается — баталиями. К сожалению, Ваш тон никак не стал мягче: Вы даже не заметили, как _пинанули_ не только меня, но и автора вопроса.